# Two different behaviors with Draggable UI helper clone and non-clone, what's going on?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-draggable, jquery-droppable

From my understanding the helper option with Draggable UI is only a display effect as described [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-helper).

But when using it with tables it appears to be bugged (append position is wrong).

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/hmj83/

```
$(".no_clone_item").draggable({
    revert: 'invalid'
});

$(".clone_item").draggable({
    helper: 'clone',
    revert: 'invalid'
});

$("td").droppable({
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        $(ui.draggable).appendTo(this);
    }
});
```

Can anyone explain this behavior or give a workaround/ fix?

Thanks.

Comment: nice demo, is there a reason you can't use draggable with clone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tim's suggested solution worked but I lost some functionality when implemented into my application.

Instead I kept the helper clone and just hid the original while dragging and redisplayed it when the dragging stopped.

```
draggable({
    start: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).hide();
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).show();

    }
});
```

Comment: oddly enough, I had an ie problem with this, but   $(this).css('opacity', '.5'); and then   $(this).css('opacity', '1'); worked okay - and it leaves a visual trail for where the gamepiece originally was

Answer (score 1):

I believe the easiest would be to reset the positioning with CSS on `.drop()`.

```
ui.draggable.css({ left: 0, top: 0 }).appendTo(this);
```

That will at least solve your problem.

**NOTE**: ui.draggable - current draggable element, **a jQuery object**.

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/tive/mJkd5/

The reason why jQuery UI adds css properties `top` and `left` to the dragged element is only for visual feedback. You can test this in your solution by adding the following CSS:

```
td img.no_clone_item {
    left: auto !important;
    top: auto !important;
}
```

With this CSS enabled, you don't have visual feedback. Only on drop the item will visually move.

When `.draggable()` receives a clone element, the position is added to the cloned element for visual feedback.